# No pay for attending

Tags: salary, overtime

My company has a 'policy' (although it is not written anywhere in our HR policy portal) that when we are required to attend training sessions and their annual conference that we are not paid for our time. They expect us to come. Is this illegal? In my contract it does not state anything about mandatory conferences or training, so I don't have to go.

Comment: You don't have to go... but they don't have to promote you either, and may not need to retain you. Then again, you may want to look elsewhere if this is really the situation.

Comment: What country are you in? If in the US, are you exempt or non-exempt?

Comment: How much time are you expected to spend on your own time? Is this training during a lunch hour? A conference on a weekend? An all day event that you're expected to either make up or take vacation time?

Comment: Do these events happen during time when you would otherwise be in the office (i.e., during the work week)?

Answer (score 3):

If it's not in your contract then you're not legally obligated to go. But it would more than likely work against you if you miss too many without good reason.

Sometimes it's worth going just for the networking and training.

I used to dodge most of them citing family obligations since I have a bunch of kids. But I went to the ones I deemed useful and learnt a few new things.

Comment: Networking to find a new employer...

Answer (score 1):

The legal side heavily depends on the situation. In France, it's both illegal(unless you're a top-level manager)...and common.

The advice side is more complicated. If you want to be legal up to the end of your fingers, and your colleagues accept not to be, plenty of unpleasant little things may happen to you. Visibility is important for career-building, and you're not building it, or maybe negatively.

There will be usually no short-term negative side-effect if you skip those unpaid events. But your political position within the firm may be damaged. And pay raises can be lower, promotions can be missed, and lay-off lists may begin by your name. So, the real answer is : it depends. If you have no plan to stay long in the firm, then by all means skip without thinking about it. If, OTOH, you have career plans there, then bite the bullet, and be a nice, concerned employee. I once made the mistake of not going(even though I was just a consultant there), and I'm blacklisted in this firm. Not all will be that tough, but you know your place better than I do.

So weigh the pros & the cons.

Answer (score 0):

> In my contract it does not state anything about mandatory conferences or training, so I don't have to go.

Did you just answer your question or are you trying to ask us that if it is not in your contract, you won't have to go?

It seems like the simple answer is to not go, but there are several unknown factors including length of training, time, and of course, what they do at these events. If it is very casual and open, then it's probably heavily promoted but not required to go to. An annual company event is not unusual and happens all over. At my prior job we held on during working hours at least once a year, but I always left a few hours early since it gets to a point where food been served, and it's now just gossiping and hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

An annual conference - Is this just a few hours per year - an opportunity to network with people?
Training - Does this new experience look good on the CV.

We all do stuff for free once in a while. Does the company measure your bathroom breaks? Are they OK with the doctors appointment, or being late for traffic.

My suggestion is that life is a bit of give and take. They may be taking a little and you are giving. But also on the flip side the converse is true.

Is this a happy median in your mind? Or would you prefer that you cannot turn up a little late once in a while or they measure the time you are in the toilet?